# Linkedin Signin Profile Picture URL in v2 API

Tags: android, ios

I am getting Profile picture URN, can anyone please help me out to get profile picture **URL** from **URN**.

here is what we getting from linkedin `r_liteprofile`.

```
{
  "lastName": {
    "localized": {
      "en_US": "lastname"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
      "country": "US",
      "language": "en"
    }
  },
  "firstName": {
    "localized": {
      "en_US": "firstname"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
      "country": "US",
      "language": "en"
    }
  },
  "profilePicture": {
    "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5603AQF_Vo5V5fn5eg"
  },
  "id": "FFeEsrZu6r"
}
```

I am already tried below format to get Profile Picture from URN

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(FFeEsrZu6r,profilePicture(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5603AQF_Vo5V5fn5eg),oauth2_access_token=AQVMHHg5ML1RXq1Et3t8qtFvIFXnviuJKaVpSZQ5IjV83hfUVn1UvIfHNNOqerVDZqXxj01w3Nn7D013Y7-oe5GT5rhltLAR55YnSaepQrxdvmbBZnfYD39r9iCnuazciSi8y8gPdZ0zmRmqgio5xlBCjkyoTKvGFCB6jAy-UA7CN9kpJr98BWGmtR4T8cIWc8h1OBzCJBwQC2DpHImN78a517uONveMt8oJeaF6pnHMZRyiyDyyj9VHv1PXP7s78rTIk4eR5Dq7GR5MPtyE-O9w0DgESNJ7Df5wjcLX4o0Zb8KKeu8UWOY6q_P91unZ9xo-mBXhATtsCghigclS98eGZS_8Xg)

Answer (score 4):

I have got answer for my mistake

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=HERE PASS ACCESS TOKEN.